# Using POST values submitted via different elements under the same page

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Title could be misleading. I do have a button with `onclick` event that calls a function to dump some values into POST variable. It also toggles a modal which have a form that POSTs to current document. A brewer example looks like this:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $_POST = [];

      function send_id(var1, var2) {
        $_POST['mainpart'] = var1;
        $_POST['subpart'] = var2;
        console.log($_POST);

      };

      function evaluate_form() {
        alert($_POST['numsales']);
      };

      function post_test() {
        console.log($_POST);
      };
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Address for sale:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="numsales">Number of sales:</label>
              <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control only-number" id="numsales" name="numsales">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="quota">Quota:</label>
              <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control only-number" id="quota" name="quota">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="evaluate_form()">Save</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">

    <h2>Performance Calculation Form</h2>

    <div class="tables">

      <div id="1">
        <form>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-md-10" colspan="2">1. Sales</th>
                <th class="col-md-2"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="col-md-8">a) Sales to a </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                  <p class="text-center">20</p>
                </td>
                <!-- <td class="col-md-2"><input name = "SCI_adedi" type="number" class="form-control" id="usr"></td> -->
                <td style="text-align: center">
                  <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" style="position: center;" onclick="send_id('1','a')">Add</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col-md-10" colspan="2">Subtotal </td>
                <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="KAYDET"> Submit</button>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

modal part:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="form1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]); ?>" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address for sale:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" rows="6"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="numsales">Number of sales:</label>
            <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control only-number" id="numsales" name="numsales">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quota">Quota:</label>
            <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control only-number" id="quota" name="quota">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="evaluate_form()">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is an 'Add' button that `onclick` event fires up `send_id(val1,val2)` function. I'm trying to dump table name and row with this `send_id()` function via POST method onto same page (Don't know if I implemented it correctly). This `Add` button also pops-up the modal. Modal have a form in it and its save button submits form with post into same page (Again not sure if I did it right way). And now I need to take all these variables and manipulate them to execute a SQL query. So I also defined an `onclick` event to modal save button to read all variables inside POST and write down a query via `evaluate_form`. Too see if I can access POST array I've used `alert($_POST);` but it bring nothing.

This may be a bad implementation but what I want to accomplish is;

- Save info about which `add` buttton is clicked. A variable is needed so I can use it when executing SQL statements(Writing into correct table).
- A model should pop after clicking `add button.`
- Modal should include a form and it should be submitted via POST into same page.
- After modal submission, all of these variables (variable of save info and modal form variables) could be acceessed via a function so SQL statements could be arranged.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this `$_POST = [];` should be `var  $_POST = {};` because you are creating object and adding new value to it so make these change and try again.

Comment: You can certainly name your Javascript variable `$_POST` but the fact that you're calling it, and attempting to use strings like 'mainpart' and 'subpart' as keys, that implies you think it's [this PHP superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). So that may be part of your confusion. JS objects can contain string keys, but JS arrays can't.

Comment: @Swati Thanks for clarification. Actually I don't want to create a new variable I just want to use global POST and append values into it. Is it possible or it is only allowed to change it via post methods?

Comment: `$_POST` is available only on server code not client side . You can save thse value in array and then pass same to your php page using ajax.